# Asymptotic behaviour meaning

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

Let $f:[0,+\infty[\to \mathbb{R}_+$ such that
$$tf(t)\to 0\quad\quad \text{as}\quad\quad t\to +\infty$$

What does asymptotic behaviour mean?

Answer (score 0):

$f(t)=o\left(\frac{1}{t}\right), t \to +\infty$

Comment: Do this mean that f behaves as $t^{-\alpha}$ with $\alpha>1$?

Comment: Yes, if understanding this in the sense that  holds $t^{-\alpha} =o\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)$, so, $f$ and $t^{-\alpha}$ with $\alpha \gt 1$ are in same class.

Comment: and it can behaves as $e^{-t}$ is that true?

Comment: I am confused how to say what does this mean

Comment: Sentence $e^{-t} =o\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)$ is also true. What worries you? Would you like to see how it follows from the definition?

Answer (score 0):

There are two common notations for "asymptotically equal" for functions $f,g:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$
$$f(x)\sim g(x)$$
and a notation I prefer
$$f(x)\asymp g(x)$$
They both mean that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$$